# How to store array values in different columns in nodejs

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, node.js

I am new in NodeJS/Mysql. I have an array of strings which I want to store in different columns of table.

No. of columns = 5 and size of array = 5 e.g. [val1, val2...]

```
  con.connect(function(err) {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log("Connected!");

    //Insert a record in the "pooltable" table:
    var sql = "INSERT INTO pooltable (`t1`, `t2`, `t3`, `t4`, `t5`) VALUES (array)";
    con.query(sql, function (err, result) {
      if (err) throw err;
      console.log("1 record inserted");
    });  
   con.end();
  });
```

Problem is I am not able to split array in 5 different values like php `implode` function.

Comment: javascript has a split function, read about it

Comment: I am using nodejs

Comment: How do you build query in php using implode?

Comment: yes i know your using javascript, so what's the problem?

Answer (score 0):

for dynamic try this

```
var arr=JSON.stringify(array).substr(1).slice(0, -1);
    var sql = 'INSERT INTO pooltable (`t1`, `t2`, `t3`, `t4`, `t5`) VALUES ("'+arr+'")';
```

Comment: Need dynamic not static

Answer (score 0):

Do you trust you user input? Are you sanitizing the data?

For Node Mysql why don't you use placeholders and just pass the array in as the parameters?

e.g

```
   con.query("INSERT INTO pooltable (`t1`, `t2`, `t3`, `t4`, `t5`) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)", arr, (err,results,fields) => {
       if(err) {return //or do something }
        // do something else
    })
```

you can find out more in the docs https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql#escaping-query-values